# Persisting entity from reference of already persisted entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Am new in jpa and i want to persist an entity(leaveTotal-which holds leave information such as allocated leave days,b/f from previous year,current month and also reference to employee and typeofleave class) Both employee and typeofleave entities have already been persisted. So,now i want to associate the LeaveTotal to both classes and then persist it.

Am using eclipselink 2.1 as the library and its a desktop application.

What i was trying is this

```
          Dept dp = getDeptByName(em, departmentComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setId(id1);
            emp.setIdnum(idTextField.getText());
            emp.setName(empnameTextField.getText());
            emp.setAddress(addressTextField.getText());
            emp.setEmail(emailTextField.getText());
            emp.setGender(genderComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            emp.setPhone(phoneTextField.getText());
            emp.setStaffcol(staffNoTextField.getText());
            emp.setDept(dp);

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            dp.getEmployeeCollection().add(emp);
            em.persist(dp);
            em.flush();
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            Leavetype lp;
            lp = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Leavetype c WHERE c.name = :name", Leavetype.class).setParameter("name", "annual").getSingleResult();
            Leavetotal lt = new Leavetotal();
            lt.setId(id1);
            lt.setAllocated(Integer.parseInt(allocatedDaysTextField.getText()));
            lt.setBalbf(Integer.parseInt(balBFTextField.getText()));
            lt.setTotal(Integer.parseInt(totalTextField.getText()));
            lt.setRem(Integer.parseInt(remainingTextField.getText()));
            lt.setMonthly(Integer.parseInt(monthlyTextField.getText()));
            lt.setMonth(getMonthForInt(monthNumber));
            lt.setStaff(emp);
            lt.setTypeName(lp);


            em.getTransaction().begin();
            emp.getLeavetotalCollection().add(lt);
            lp.getLeavetotalCollection().add(lt);
            em.persist(emp);
            em.persist(lp);
            em.flush();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: so whats your question ? any error ?

Comment: Leavetotal will only be persisted if cascade persist is set on the employee or leavetype relations to it.  Otherwise it should throw an exception